# When I use simpleLogger to get the response content, the information obtained is garbled

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

When I run testcafe code, the output from this step is garbled.:

```
for (let i = simpleLogger.requests.length - 1; i > 0; i--) { let url_test = simpleLogger.requests[i].request.url; if (url_test.indexOf("/gt/validate/") !== -1) { let res_json = simpleLogger.requests[i].response.body console.log(res_json); break; } }
```

Then I turned on the browser debug mode and found that there was an extra piece of js code in the return content of each page request：

```
/*hammerhead|script|start*/if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window){window['hammerhead|process-dom-method'] && window['hammerhead|process-dom-method']();if (window.__get$ && typeof __get$ === 'undefined') {var __get$Loc = window.__get$Loc,__set$Loc = window.__set$Loc,__set$ = window.__set$,__get$ = window.__get$,__call$ = window.__call$,__get$Eval = window.__get$Eval,__proc$Script = window.__proc$Script,__proc$Html = window.__proc$Html,__get$PostMessage = window.__get$PostMessage,__get$ProxyUrl = window.__get$ProxyUrl,__rest$Array = window.__rest$Array,__rest$Object = window.__rest$Object;}} else {var __get$Loc = function(l){return l},__set$Loc = function(l,v){return l = v},__set$ = function(o,p,v){return o[p] = v},__get$ = function(o,p){return o[p]},__call$ = function(o,p,a){return o[p].apply(o,a)},__get$Eval = function(e){return e},__proc$Script = function(s){return s},__proc$Html = function(h){return h},__get$PostMessage = function(w,p){return arguments.length===1?w.postMessage:p},__get$ProxyUrl = function(u,d){return u},__rest$Array = function(a,i){return Array.prototype.slice.call(a, i)},__rest$Object = function(o,p){var k=Object.keys(o),n={};for(var i=0;i<k.length;++i)if(p.indexOf(k[i])<0)n[k[i]]=o[k[i]];return n};}/*hammerhead|script|processing-header-end*/ geetest_1610940527001({"theme_version": "1.2.4", "clean": false, "so": 0, "mobile": true, "xpos": 0, "version": "6.0.9", "ypos": 37, "gt": "53eb2795e892363b5a7e6c0df0ed74af", "feedback": "http://www.geetest.com/contact#report", "id": "a738db9d4442c5fd0bcbe65865085aa96", "benchmark": false, "gct_path": "/static/js/gct.1.0.0.js", "type": "multilink", "template": "", "width": "100%", "hide_delay": 800, "fullpage": false, "api_server": "http://g1-server-staging.kjy.gtapp.xyz/", "challenge": "738db9d4442c5fd0bcbe65865085aa96g3", "height": 160, "s": "7a69353a", "https": false, "slice": "pictures/gt/d49a453dc/slice/8acfcf53c.png", "bg": "pictures/gt/d49a453dc/bg/8acfcf53c.jpg", "show_delay": 250, "logo": true, "i18n_labels": {"cancel": "\u53d6\u6d88", "loading": "\u52a0\u8f7d\u4e2d...", "fail": "\u8bf7\u6b63\u786e\u62fc\u5408\u56fe\u50cf", "refresh": "\u5237\u65b0\u9a8c\u8bc1", "close": "\u5173\u95ed\u9a8c\u8bc1", "error": "\u8bf7\u91cd\u8bd5", "feedback": "\u5e2e\u52a9\u53cd\u9988", "read_reversed": false, "tip": "\u8bf7\u5b8c\u6210\u4e0b\u65b9\u9a8c\u8bc1", "voice": "\u89c6\u89c9\u969c\u788d", "logo": "\u7531\u6781\u9a8c\u63d0\u4f9b\u6280\u672f\u652f\u6301", "slide": "\u62d6\u52a8\u6ed1\u5757\u5b8c\u6210\u62fc\u56fe", "success": "sec \u79d2\u7684\u901f\u5ea6\u8d85\u8fc7 score% \u7684\u7528\u6237", "forbidden": "\u602a\u7269\u5403\u4e86\u62fc\u56fe\uff0c\u8bf7\u91cd\u8bd5"}, "product": "embed", "c": [12, 58, 98, 36, 43, 95, 62, 15, 12], "link": "", "static_servers": ["static.geetest.com/", "dn-staticdown.qbox.me/"], "fullbg": "pictures/gt/d49a453dc/d49a453dc.jpg", "theme": "ant"}) /*hammerhead|script|end*/
```

How can I get what I want through simplelogger (except hammerhead)
hope to give me an answer

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the following articles:
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/intercept-http-requests.html#log-http-requests

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requestlogger/constructor.html

You need to pass the 'logResponseBody: true' argument to the RequestLogger constructor as follows:

```
const headerLogger = RequestLogger(/testcafe/, {
    logResponseBody: true
});
```

In this case, the `body` will be of the Buffer type, so you need to convert it into string. Otherwise, you can use the `stringifyResponseBody: true` argument to convert it automatically.

Please also check if your response is compressed as gzip. In this case you need to unzip it self as described in the following threads:

[How to get the json response of a RequestLogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972855/how-to-get-the-json-response-of-a-requestlogger)

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/3243

Regarding the `/*hammerhead|script|start*/if (typeof window !== 'undefined'` part. This is code injected by TestCafe into a tested page. It does not interfere with your requests and is not logged.